# What could prevent a custom application from setting up a SQLite database?

Tags: android, sqlite, windows-8.1

I have an application that generates a database and defining tables on installation.  Well.. it is supposed to.  Thing is: this application has failed and continues to fail to setup the SQLite database on a random selection of computers.  So far 8% of the computers fail to install the SQLite database my app requires to function.

Now I am not a database guy so I don't have the knowledge to understand what could be going on in the background.  I just wanted to see if somebody has had this problem and if they found a solution, or if there is a prerequisite for a computer to install an SQLite database from an app such as .NET Framework or CLR.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: where is the database being written to?  It is likely a permission issue that doesn't allow the account running the program to write a file to.  SQLite is merely a file structure.  Try creating a text file in that same location to see if that works.

Comment: @AndrewK The database is written to C:\users\<current account>\AppData\Local\Packages\<App package>\LocalState. I was able to save a text file to the location.

Comment: there should be permissions to write to that directory.  do you have all the dll's needed in the application's executable installation folder?  Perhaps put the code you are using to create the initial database in your question would make this easier.

Comment: @AndrewK, I can't be absolutely certain if all the dlls are in the installation folder; this is the first Windows 8.1 Store app I have had a hand in developing.  But given the fact that I can install the app correctly on other computers in the same environment,  I find the idea of necessary files in the app package missing unlikely.  However, I will consider that as a possible issue.

Comment: @AndrewK Thanks for your assistance in providing me with a fresh perspective.  It was discovered that some of the core Windows 8.1 licenses were missing/corrupted.  And that led to missing files that the App required to function.